# FluentValidation preload data

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I want validate a request model with some ids. I try to preload all required data with a bulk request.
The problem is the `RuleForEach` inside my `WhereAsync` is called before the `LoadUserGroupsAsync` is done or started. I start the validation with `TestValidateAsync(request)`.

Is there a better solution for this I have unfortunately not found any solutions for it. Also I have no access to the model from outside a `RuleFor`, `RuleForEach`, `Where`, ...

```
private readonly List<UserGroup> _userGroups;
```

```
WhenAsync(async (request, cancellationToken) => await this.LoadUserGroupsAsync(request.Items, cancellationToken), () =>
{
    RuleForEach(o => o.Items).SetValidator(new UserUpdateValidator(this._userGroups));
});
```

```
private async Task<bool> LoadUserGroupsAsync(UserUpdateDto[] userUpdates, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var ids = userUpdates.Select(o => o.userGroupId);
    this._userGroups = await this._userGroupService.GetByIdsAsync(ids, cancellationToken);

    return true;
}
```

```
public class UserUpdateValidator : AbstractValidator<UserUpdateDto>
{
    public UserUpdateValidator(
       UserGroup[] groups)
    {
        RuleFor(item => item.UserGroupId).Must(userGroupId =>
        {
            var group = groups.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == userGroupId);
            if (group == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }).WithMessage("Group is invalid");

        RuleFor(item => item.UserGroupId).Must(userGroupId =>
        {
            var group = groups.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == userGroupId);
            return group.Active;
        }).WithMessage("Group is inactive");

        RuleFor(item => item.Password).Must((context, password) =>
        {
            var group = groups.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == context.UserGroupId);
            if (group.Permissions.Contains("AllowPasswordChange"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }).WithMessage("It is now allowed to change the password for your user");
    }
}
```

**Update 2021-04-28** - Add more Informations to example

Comment: Instead of fixing this in your validator, implementing caching in your users service might be a better solution. Unfortunately I cannot post an answer recommending this, because I would need to see more code. Basically all the code in your validator, and enough of the code in your users service to help craft a solution. But that would be my suggestion. Add caching to the users service.

Comment: @GregBurghardt For example, I want to check the groups of users if they exist. But now I would have to load them separately for each group id. Also if I implement a caching I would have to implement a logic that invalidates the cache on update. So I would prefer a logic where I preload the groups once for all users in the request.

Comment: Can you please add more of the validator class? I *think* I have a solution, but I just don't have enough information. I need to see the entire validator class.

Comment: @GregBurghardt i have improve the question

Comment: Please add the code for the upper level validator - the validator that initializes the child validators.

Comment: I think I have enough info. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy loading and a wrapper object for the users. This would require calling sync methods instead of async methods to load the users, however.

You could use a `Lazy<IEnumerable<User>>` object, but that would probably require refactoring your child validator. I like creating a wrapper class for `Lazy<IEnumerable<User>>` just to make the code backwards-compatible for any other code accepting `IEnumerable<T>` objects:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a lazy loaded enumerable of type T
/// </summary>
public class LazyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<T>> items;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new lazy loaded enumerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemFactory">A lambda expression that returns the items to be iterated over.</param>
    public LazyEnumerable(Func<IEnumerable<T> itemFactory)
    {
        items = new Lazy<T>>(itemFactory);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new lazy loaded enumerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemFactory">The Lazy<T> object used to lazily retrieve the items to be iterated over.</param>
    public LazyEnumerable(Lazy<IEnumerable<T>> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.Value.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.Value.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This is actually a general purpose class that can be used for any type. I wish .NET had this class in its base library, to be honest. I tend to copy and paste this in to every project, because it is so easy to use. In any event...

Then modify your validator class. Since you did not post enough code for your validator, I took a few guesses about the names of things and structure of your code:

```
public class YourValidator : AbstractValidator<X>
{
    private UserService _userService;
    private IEnumerable<UserGroup> _userGroups;

    public YourValidator(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;

        When((request, cancellationToken) => PreloadUserGroups(request.Items, cancellationToken), () =>
        {
            RuleForEach(o => o.Items).SetValidator(new UserUpdateValidator(_userGroups));
        });
    }

    private bool PreloadUserGroups(UserUpdateDto[] userUpdates, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var ids = userUpdates.Select(o => o.userGroupId);

        _userGroups = new LazyEnumerable<UserGroup>(() => _userService.GetByIds(ids, cancellationToken));

        return true;
    }
}
```

This will lazy load the users, and since you pass the same object to all child validators it will load the users only once, regardless of how many times the collection is iterated.

Lastly, modify your child validator class to accept an `IEnumerable<UserGroup>` object instead of an array:

```
public class UserUpdateValidator : AbstractValidator<UserUpdateDto>
{
    public UserUpdateValidator(IEnumerable<UserGroup> groups)
```